# Data structure for huge amount of records with ability to do "GetAllWithPrefix" fast

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, data-structures

I need an in-memory data structure to store lots of values (~10M records) of type `string` with length of up to 100 characters (just in case it helps).

I'm going to run the following operations extensively:

1. Add
2. Get
3. Remove
4. GetAllWithPrefix(string prefix) - returns a list of all values corresponding to the prefix.

Obviously, any of the above operations need to be done in `O(1)` or `O(logn)`

I'm a bit rusty. What would be the best data structure for that? preferably direct me to the right class.

Thank you

Comment: Using a database is out of the question?

Comment: yes.. it should be in-memory.

Comment: So that's a "yes, I cannot use a database" as well as "it should be in-memory"? Because there are in-memory databases, like sqlite.

Comment: However, one of the various tree data structures are probably your best bet if you intend to do a lot of add/remove interleaved.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have no experience with sqlite so I'm not sure about its performance. But this data structure is going to be used in a class that represents a cache layer, that precedes Redis cache.

Comment: Dictionary for O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a trie, which is a tree where  each node has a map of character to nodes (branch) and a walk in the trie is a prefix walk, certain nodes also have a flag that implies if it's at the end of a string stored in the trie even though there could be further branches from node (string is prefix of another added string). A normal implementation has complexity: Insertion O(w), lookup is O(w) and prefix search is O(w+n) where w is string length and n is total length of words in the tree with w as prefix.

You can read about one c# implementation here

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx?m=1

**Update**
I want to clarify that the time complexities above in your special case is actually O(1) when considering your string length has an upper limit of 100.